# Low voltage at receptical!

Tags: electrical-panel

I have only 1 receptacle being designated to 1 individual breaker, so when I shut the main breaker off I only lose power in that one receptacle in the entire house.
When the main breaker is turned back on I get a reading of 120v at the main breaker but when I go to the only receptacle it’s connected to it only reads between 80v and 90v (I did this with the wires connected to the receptacle and also not conneced and got the same reading).
There does not seem to be another receptacle connected, so I don’t know what the problem is! Please help.

Comment: Which country are you in? Electrical systems differ around the world.

Comment: Probably a bad/damaged/loose wire somewhere between the breaker and the receptacle.